# A calculation of a function in reverse order in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
//@version=5    
indicator("My script")

in_time_start = input.time(timestamp("01 Aug 2022 00:00 +0000"), "Start Time")    
in_time_end = input.time(timestamp("31 Dec 2031 00:00 +0000"), "End Time")

time_in_window = (time >= in_time_start and time <= in_time_end)    
var float your_variable = 0.0    
your_variable += time_in_window ? ((open + close) / open) : your_variable

plot(your_variable)
```

Please tell me how to calculate this function in reverse order (from right to left)?

For example:

```
((open[50] + close[50]) / open[50]) + ((open [49] + close[49]) / open[49]) +
```

etc.

In short the calculation of the function begins with a last bar in a chart - how does it do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a for loop.

```
sum = 0.0

for i=50 to 0
    sum := sum + ((open[i] + close[i]) / open[i])
```

Comment: I tried to use a for loop but a calculation with it is incorrect. It doesn't work for this function, u can try also. If I change so: i=o to 50, it turns out the same. But this is impossible... In short this method doesn't work with the function. Is it the only method?

Comment: @tgstl i think you need to append "by -1" in for loop and then use it like [math.abs(i)] with open,close